# Cannot update profile: Invalid image type

Tags: bug, profile-page, error-message, image-upload

I see this used to be an issue, but every question I find indicates that it was fixed. I even found a thread indicating that it was once an issue which was fixed and which had been unfixed; but that thread is old, so this seems to be an oft-recurring bug.

Once again, if I try to edit my profile (specifically adding to the "about me" section), I'm told of an invalid image type. There is no image in the text I'm adding. I have neither added nor altered any images whatsoever; only added text to an input field.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but there are some ongoing issues with image provider SE uses. I don't believe those issues are yet fixed. The error you get might be related to those issues. In that case it is not your  fault and there is nothing you can do to resolve it. I've retagged your question so the SE dev working on those bugs is aware of your issue as well.